# Need to grab Selected Option value from a form and pass back via jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I need to dynamically grab the value of whatever option has been selected by a user and pass that value back to the Facebook Pixel on button click.

See **SELECTED OPTION VALUE** in the script area.

```
      <form action="/cart/add" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="AddToBagForm text-center medium-up--text-left" novalidate>    
        <select name="id" id="product-select-2585865157" class="product-single__variants">
              <option  selected="selected"  value="7534116741">White Marble / S - $39.95 USD</option>
              <option  value="7534116869">White Marble / L - $39.95 USD</option>
              <option  value="7534117061">Midnight / S - $39.95 USD</option>
              <option  value="7534117253">Midnight / L - $39.95 USD</option>
              <option  value="9032311493">Maroon / M - $39.95 USD</option>
              <option  value="9032318853">Maroon / L - $39.95 USD</option>
        </select>   
        <div class="add-container clearfix">   
          <a href="#" class="btn--primary BIS_trigger" data-product-handle="mighty-ganesh-flowy-top" data-variant-id="7534116741">Get Notified</a>
          <div class="quantity-field">
            <label for="Quantity" class="quantity-selector">Qty:</label>
            <input type="number" id="Quantity" name="quantity" value="1" min="1" max="3" class="quantity-selector">
          </div>
          <button type="submit" name="add" class="AddToBag btn--primary" id="add-to-cart" >
            <span class="AddToBagText">Add to Bag</span>
          </button>  
        </div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
          $('#add-to-cart').click(function() {
            fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
              content_ids: '{{ product.id }}.' + **SELECTED OPTION VALUE**,
              content_type: 'product',
              value: {{ product.price | money_without_currency}},
            });
          });
        </script>

      </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get a `select` element's selected option value [through the `.val()` function with jQuery](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/faq/how-do-i-get-the-text-value-of-a-selected-option/) since you already use the library.

`$('#product-select-2585865157').val()`

Or, since that `id` seems to be generated: `$('select.product-single__variants').val()`

Your final JavaScript should look like this:

```
 $('#add-to-cart').click(function() {
      var selection = $('#product-select-2585865157').val();
      /* var selection = $('select.product-single__variants').val(); */

      fbq('track', 'AddToCart', {
          content_ids: '{{ product.id }}.' + selection,
          content_type: 'product',
          value: {{ product.price | money_without_currency}},
      });
 });
```

Comment: Thanks. I will check it shortly. One quick followup question: the product-select-# is dynamic, using one of Shopify's internal variables:
<select name="id" id="product-select-{{ product.id }}" class="product-single__variants">. 
So, I can't hard code that long number into my solution. How would I incorporate that into the variable assigment?

Comment: My answer was updated to grab the value with the select's class instead (see the commented code).